# Is there a word/name that sounds like "Arky"?

Tags: word-choice, names

I'm looking for a catchy name and I'm wondering if the word "arky" does mean anything in the Chinese language.

I was wondering if there is like a word in Chinese language that is pronounced (not written) the same as „arky“ and what would it mean...

Comment: What does "arky" mean in your language?

Comment: A catchy name for what? A person? A business? A book? A movie? A poem? ... If you want to get any meaningful answer, please supply more information. Also "Arky" is not a Chinese word, so it does not mean anything in the Chinese language. But a transliteration might land you something interesting. I am not ruling that out.

Comment: No, it is not Chinese. It is neither a Chinese character nor proper PinYin. There is no Chinese word that has such pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like having a sneeze.
"阿嚏", "ā tì"

Comment: lol made me laugh

Comment: "阿嚏", "ā tì" in the Fujian dialect sounds like "little brother" Maybe this suits OP's purpose? Looks like the OP has lost interest in his or her own post?